# making the footer fixed with bootstrap css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Here is codepen demo of my page. Footer is not fixed in this case which I want to make fixed on its position.

[**CODEPEN DEMO**](http://codepen.io/karimkhan/pen/mjKyc)

I tried with :

```
class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation"
```

But it then changes the color and created messup with my existing preview.

How to make it fixed without affecting existing page.

Comment: Your codepen is really messy. Can you refine it to a minimal example? `navbar-default` will add style/color to the navbar, while `navbar-fixed-bottom` will attach it to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

try this it's workinig for me, add this in your css :

```
#footer
{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
/*background:beige;*/
}
```